# Outdated row doesn't move out from foreign table partition postgres

Tags: postgresql, sharding

I'm trying to learn how sharding is configured in Postgres.

My Postgres setup has a `temperature` table which has 4 partitions each covering different range of "timestamp" value.

```
postgres=# \d+ temperature
                                                     Partitioned table "public.temperature"
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | Storage | Stats target | Description 
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id        | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('temperature_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 city_id   | integer                     |           | not null |                                         | plain   |              | 
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |                                         | plain   |              | 
 temp      | numeric(5,2)                |           | not null |                                         | main    |              | 
Partition key: RANGE ("timestamp")
Partitions: temperature_201901 FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2019-02-01 00:00:00'),
            temperature_201902 FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-02-01 00:00:00') TO ('2019-03-01 00:00:00'),
            temperature_201903 FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-03-01 00:00:00') TO ('2019-04-01 00:00:00'),
            temperature_201904 FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-04-01 00:00:00') TO ('2019-05-01 00:00:00')
```

`temperature_201904` table, in particular, is a foreign table

```
postgres=# \d+ temperature_201904 
                                                           Foreign table "public.temperature_201904"
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | FDW options | Storage | Stats target | Description 
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id        | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('temperature_id_seq'::regclass) |             | plain   |              | 
 city_id   | integer                     |           | not null |                                         |             | plain   |              | 
 timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |                                         |             | plain   |              | 
 temp      | numeric(5,2)                |           | not null |                                         |             | main    |              | 
Partition of: temperature FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-04-01 00:00:00') TO ('2019-05-01 00:00:00')
Partition constraint: (("timestamp" IS NOT NULL) AND ("timestamp" >= '2019-04-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2019-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Server: shard02
```

Insert works as expected. If I insert the following value and check from the remote host `shard02`, then the value exists. Fantastic!

```
postgres=# select * from temperature_201904;
 id | city_id |      timestamp      | temp  
----+---------+---------------------+-------
  1 |       1 | 2019-04-02 00:00:00 | 12.30
(1 row)
```

However, if I update the timestamp of this row such that it's no longer valid for the range defined for the partition, I'd expect it to get moved out and placed into the correct partition, `temperature_201901`, but it's not.

```
postgres=# update temperature set timestamp =  '2019-01-04' where id=1;
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select * from temperature_201904 ;
 id | city_id |      timestamp      | temp  
----+---------+---------------------+-------
  1 |       1 | 2019-01-04 00:00:00 | 12.30
```

Again, just to reiterate, this table has a range `temperature_201904 FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-04-01 00:00:00') TO ('2019-05-01 00:00:00')` and is a foreign table.

Feels like I'm missing something here.

Is this an expected behavior? If so, is there a way to configure such that data are automatically moved between nodes as their partition constraints are changed?

Thanks in advance!

```
postgres=# SELECT version();
                                                     version                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Comment: I don't know if that is expected or a bug, best ask the pgsql-hackers mailing list. But if you ever update partitioning keys in a real-life workload, you got a bad design.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe "But if you ever update partitioning keys in a real-life workload, you got a bad design"  I think an important use case for partitioning is to be physically moving rows individually (as the key is updated one at a time) so that future bulk operations like bulk deletion or archiving are less traumatic.

Comment: @jjames If you say so... I think that the main point of partitioning is that you do **not** have to do bulk deletes or updates, but drop or reattach a partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be expected.  From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html)

> While rows can be moved from local partitions to a foreign-table partition (provided the foreign data wrapper supports tuple routing), they cannot be moved from a foreign-table partition to another partition.

Now I would have expected an ERROR rather than silently violating the implied constraint, but I wouldn't expect this to have worked the way to you want it to.